# Como ainda é possível calcular 1<<64-1, sem emitir um overflow?

Tags: tipagem, golang

O limite do uint64 é de (2^64)-1, *ou simplesmente 1<<64-1*. Quando tenta fazer algo como `fmt.Print(uint64(1<<64-1))` ele funciona normalmente, o faz sentido uma vez que está dentro do limite.

Porém, se o `1<<64` ultrapassa o limite, como ainda é possível calcular o `1<<64-1`, *sem uso de `big.Int` e afins*?

Minha questão é como que é possível fazer:

```
fmt.Print(uint64(1<<65-1<<64-1))
```

Se o `1<<65` ultrapassa o limite do uint64, em que formato isto está? Existe um nome especifico para isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note que há uma otimização e o compilador *folda* tudo isto para o número do resultado e não executa nada, fica o mesmo que escrever o número literal, que sempre é uma constante. Se você colocar uma simples variável já enrosca:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main(){
    x := uint32(64)
    fmt.Print(uint64(1 << 65 - 1 << x - 1))
}
```

Veja [**não** funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/tMVvcp). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ctzxsajz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Go/Optimization.go).

Então transformando em um valor constante é possível trabalhar desta forma de acordo com a [especificação](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants), o que eu considero um erro porque muda a semântica sem motivo aparente, daí a pergunta é muito pertinente. Deve ter um motivo, mas para mim constante deveria ter a mesma semântica da variável exceto pelo fato que seu valor nunca muda e permitir alguma otimização.

Answer (score 1):

Isso ocorre porque o valor `1<<65-1<<64-1)` não é tratado como um `uint64` durante a execução, mas como uma [Constant Expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions) durante a compilação, podendo conter apenas [Constants](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants).

Segundo a especificação:

> Constant expressions are always evaluated exactly; intermediate values
>   and the constants themselves may require precision significantly
>   larger than supported by any predeclared type in the language.

Tradução livre:

> *Constant Expressions* são sempre calculadas de forma exata; valores intermediários e as próprias constantes podem necessitar de uma
>   precisão significativamente maior que qualquer tipo declarado pela
>   linguagem.

Segundo a especificação da linguagem, tais constantes (do tipo inteiro) devem ser representadas com, no mínimo, 256 bits. A versão atual da linguagem suporta uma precisão de até [512 bits](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/constant/value.go#L63). Caso seja feita uma operação que ultrapasse esse limite, um erro será lançado. Exemplo:

```
fmt.Print(uint64(1 << 512))
```

O trecho acima gera o seguinte erro: `shift count too large: 512`.

Caso o resultado da *Constant Expression* seja um valor maior que o suportado ou diferente do tipo declarado, o compilador irá identificar isso como um erro.